# I have an array with values and a map in node js. How do I create null values for the non existent values in map?

Tags: node.js

I have an array with values and a map in node js. How do I create null values for the non existent values in map?

```
map = [
  { CATALOG: "123", ASSEMBLY_ID: "abc" },
  { CATALOG: "456", ASSEMBLY_ID: "pqr" },
];
array = ["abc", "def", "xyz", "pqr"];
```

expected output

```
map = [
  { CATALOG: "123", cost: "abc" },
  { CATALOG: "456", cost: "pqr" },
  { CATALOG: null, cost: "def" },
  { CATALOG: null, cost: "xyz" },
];
```

Comment: Share your code as well!

Comment: this is the code!I just want to  check and create a null value with the cost..however don't see to get the workaround

Comment: for(var i=0;i<map.length;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<assid.length;j++)
    {
        if(map[i].ASSEMBLY_ID==assid[j])
        {
           
        }
        else
        {
            map.push({"CATALOG":null,"ASSEMBLY_ID":assid[i]})
            
            
        }
    }
}
console.log(map)   this is the code I 've written and the output I get is huge...there something wrong in loops

Comment: const mapWithNull = array.map(itemId => ({
  CATALOG: map.find(item => item.ASSEMBLY_ID === itemId) ? map.find(item => item.ASSEMBLY_ID === itemId).CATALOG : null,
  cost: itemId
}))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robust solution would be:

```js
const result = array.map(el => {
    const correspondingItem = map.find(e => e.ASSEMBLY_ID === el)
    return ({CATALOG: null, ...correspondingItem, ASSEMBLY_ID: el});
})
```

But if you want some flexibility with yours fields, you may iterate over obj fields:

```js
const classKeys = Object.keys(map[0]);
const result = array.map(el => {
    const correspondingItem = map.find(e => e.ASSEMBLY_ID === el);
    return classKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = correspondingItem?.[key] || null
        return acc
    }, {})
})
```

For more comprehensive cases I would suggest to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- This can be achieved using

  - first convert the given array of object to an object, to make it easy to perform search later.
  - Later map/loop over the given array and search the given keys in the object created in above step and thus assign the value of key 'CATALOG' conditionally on basis of whether or not it was found in the initially given array of object.

```js
let theMap = [
  { CATALOG: "123", ASSEMBLY_ID: "abc" },
  { CATALOG: "456", ASSEMBLY_ID: "pqr" },
];

let theArray = ["abc", "def", "xyz", "pqr"];

let theMap2 = theMap.reduce((obj, cur) => 
  ({...obj, [cur.ASSEMBLY_ID]: cur}), 
  {}
);

let output = theArray.map(x=>({
  'CATALOG': theMap2[x]?.CATALOG || null, 
  'cost': x
}));

console.log({output});
```